# Discord js skipping token verification to allow discord self bot on latest versions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I understand the risks involved with self botting, wanted to know if there is any way to edit the code to allow for user tokens to be used on the latest version, using the older versions have proven problematic.

Comment: As far as I know, self bots are already possible on the latest version

Comment: @Nathan how would you do it on discord.js? the official npm?

Comment: @Nathan still gives me the invalid token provided error, for discord user tokens

Comment: Are you sure you are using the token and not the ID ? The token can only be found in [your navigator dev tools](https://youtu.be/gQyPwPkSKJ4?t=195)

Comment: @Nathan 100% sure, im trying to use a discord user token. The thing is they dropped support for user tokens in V12 the Discord.js NPM unless you made edits to src dont think you can log in with user tokens.